# Regex, negative lookahead for a part of expression

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds, regex-group

i'm evaluating an expression using regex patterns.
In an expression, I have words. I want to forbid some reserved words like *true* and *false* (but i want to accept words like obs*true*nt)

So I define, for example, this pattern for a word:

```
(?!^true$)(?!^false$)[^ =]{1,50}
```

Ok, this works fine for a single word, but it doesn't to evaluate an expression. 
Let us assume that an expression is always an assignment, this pattern

```
((?!^true$)(?!^false$)[^ =]{1,50})=((?!^true$)(?!^false$)[^ =]{1,50})
```

doesn't work. In fact it match *true=false*

What can I do to avoid this problem? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a general case, you need to use custom boundaries here, since your words are chunks of characters other than whitespace and `=`:

```
(?<![^\s=])(?!(?:true|false)(?![^=\s]))[^\s=]{1,50}(?![^=\s])
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/ccwUUh/2).

**Details**

- `(?<![^\s=])` - a location in the string that is not immediately preceded with a char other than whitespace and `=`
- `(?!(?:true|false)(?![^=\s]))` - immediately to the right, there should be no `true` and `false` that are followed with a `=`, whitespace or end of string
- `[^\s=]{1,50}` - one ot fifty chars other than whitespace and `=`
- `(?![^=\s])` - immediately to the right, there should be no character other than `=` or whitespace.

To validate the assignment, you may use

```
^(?!(?:true|false)=)[^\s=]{1,50}=(?!(?:true|false)$)[^\s=]{1,50}$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/ccwUUh/1)

Here, at the start, the `true` or `false` are curbed with `=` on the right and then, on the right, with a  `$` (end of string).

Comment: Yeah, it's work, thanks. The main problem is that the program is more complicated and the parts of an expression pattern is stored in different classes. For example, Word.getPattern()+Operator.getPattern()+Word.getPattern()
So i need patterns that works fine alone and also combined with others.

Comment: @Kaysan Just use the "stoppers", boundaries, in the form of lookarounds, just as I have shown. You know the context, you will have to find them on your own. If you need more help, please check the contexts where the words should not be matched, edit the question  and let me know.

Comment: Ok, i think i've understood. Thank you!

Comment: @Kaysan Please also consider upvoting if my answer proved helpful to you.